# Spring logs before running test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging

Before running my test spring is generating info logs. How to turn it off?

```
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.28
Mar 24, 2022 10:19:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_321\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\opt\apache-maven-3.8.4\bin;C:\opt\gradle-2.8\bin;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin;C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\;C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\;C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\opt\apache-maven-3.8.4\bin;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin;;.]
Mar 24, 2022 10:19:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
Mar 24, 2022 10:19:11 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader prepareWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2117 ms
Mar 24, 2022 10:19:11 PM org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean configure
INFO: Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
Mar 24, 2022 10:19:11 PM org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean configure
INFO: Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
Mar 24, 2022 10:19:11 PM org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean configure
INFO: Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
Mar 24, 2022 10:19:11 PM org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean configure
INFO: Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
Mar 24, 2022 10:19:12 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter initControllerAdviceCache
INFO: Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@2cc3ad05: startup date [Thu Mar 24 22:19:09 CET 2022]; root of context hierarchy
Mar 24, 2022 10:19:12 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
Mar 24, 2022 10:19:12 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
Mar 24, 2022 10:19:12 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
```

application.properties

```
logging.level.root=WARN
spring.main.banner-mode=off
logging.pattern.console=
logging.level.org.springframework.*=ERROR
logging.level.org.springframework.web=OFF
logging.level.org.hibernate=ERROR
logging.level.org.springframework.core=OFF
```

I have also logback file in resources directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml" />
    <logger name="org.springframework" level="ERROR"/>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Make sure you indicate the properties similar to `application.properties` in your `src/test/resources` folder as well

Comment: @SpringBootTest() is generating logs

Answer (score 0):

Move the `logback-test.xml` file to the `/src/test/resources/` instead of `src/main/resources`